# Realm causes my app to crash when trying to build a RealmConfiguration

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to use Realm as a database for high scores in my app. However, when this line of code is called:

```
realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).build();
```

in the Fragment where I'm trying to save the user's score, I get this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tommy.mastersproject, PID: 21387
Theme: themes:{com.android.settings=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/realm/RealmConfiguration$Builder;
at com.tommy.mastersproject.fragments.MemoryRecallFragment.onCreate(MemoryRecallFragment.java:144)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1951)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:779)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:802)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:660)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:601)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_d80f4a0fc2ae8e1f7cf76e4c536a48795da28487-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-library-2.4.0_e0d22a6e7ea9a4d2326a0c8c16bbc09d4d04442c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_bd67bdb6ef0c094e8f4157e2567e8b30b9d0dd7f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.jakewharton-butterknife-8.0.1_9246a0d023a2de89ba20a84f0fb1ecc6b733b004-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.code-troopers.betterpickers-library-3.0.0_f98f8b23c6650d93d8479a647f8f2162db8834e8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.astuetz-pagerslidingtabstrip-1.0.1_474986b4f5d06e547dc72e3bf0988a95fa9d3973-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.tommy.mastersproject/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-dr
```

I've also tried using

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

but without any luck.

From a quick Google search, there have been similar complaints which were due to Realm's poor compatibility with the Android multidex and for not being up-to-date with Gradle, but I'm currently running Gradle 2.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also using Gradle 2.1.2 and Realm is working perfectly fine, problem could be with Instant Run, Did you try loading the project without Instant Run? If not disable it(In Android studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run), clean the project and run it again.

If it does not work, share the actual code where you are creating RealmConfiguration and using Realm.

Comment: I was using Instant Run. I followed your suggestion of switching that off, and now the app works. I wonder if it's something to do with Realm creating their own Gradle plugin.

Comment: Great, glad it worked, It's more of an Instant Run problem & not Realm. Realm Gradle plugin had few issues, but with recent updates major issues are fixed.